# Are there resources to ask "Check my understanding?" questions not suitable for SE?

Tags: resource-request, french

I am learning French, and I am at a beginner level. I sometimes ask specific grammar-related questions on french.stackexchange .

However, this is not enough help to motivate me for learning French. I often come across sentences where I want to ask questions about the sentences, in one of the following two ways:

1. Where I think I probably understand the grammar construction or
   meaning of the sentence, but I want a French speaker to confirm that my
   understanding is in fact correct.
2. I want to dialogue about interesting tentative linguistic
   observations I have about the sentence, but I don't have a specific
   question. This dialogue motivates me, because it expands
   my general understanding of the linguistic context/underpinnings of French, English, and other
   languages, in a way that I could not anticipate with a specific question.

The occasional question in the first case is allowed on French.stackexchange, but it would be inappropriate for me to ask too many of these questions. The open-ended dialogue of the second case is completely prohibited on all stack exchange sites.

However, being able to ask both of these kinds of questions are crucial to my motivation.

I do not have friends or teachers who are consistently willing to discuss these things with me.

Questions:
1. Are there internet resources where it's okay to ask many questions to confirm my understanding of French sentences that I come across?
2. Are there internet resources where it's okay to present my own curious linguistic observations/questions about French and English sentences, and to have linguists give me some of the fuller linguistic understandings that they are reminded of when they read my initial questions?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a language exchange with a French native speaker? I find a language exchange with a native speaker to be a great way to ask many questions, because the language partner is also able to ask a lot of questions about your language. That way neither feel burdened by the other. Of course it is necessary to find a language partner, who is up for it.

Comment: I do like the point of mutual not-being-burdened; but my questions really are grammar-based (e.g. "am i constructing this sentence correctly?") and so they do require the person answering to be good at grammar.

Comment: Then you have to get lucky to find the right person or it might be necessary to go to a professional teacher. There are quite a few websites, where you can find native teachers and some of them have very affordable prices. One example would be [italki](https://www.italki.com/).